# Firebase httpsCallable emulator thwrowing unhandled promise rejection in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, react-native

I have a Firebase function that searches for a user by uid:

```
export const findUserByUid = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const foundUser = await admin.auth().getUser(data.uid);

    if (foundUser) {
        return {user: foundUser.email};
    }

    return {user: null};
});
```

The functions are served by following command: `npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions`

In React Native I initialize Firebase this way:

```
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";
import firebase from "firebase";

let firebaseConfig: Object = {
   ...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const firebaseStore = firebaseApp.firestore();
const firebaseAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
const firebaseFunction = firebaseApp.functions();

if (__DEV__) {
    console.log("Initialize emulator for cloud functions");
    firebaseFunction.useEmulator('localhost', 5001);
    console.log(firebaseFunction)
}

export {firebaseStore, firebaseAuth, firebaseFunction};
```

Call of the firebase function:

```
const findUser = async (): Promise<void> => {
        const findUserByUid = await firebaseFunction.httpsCallable('findUserByUid')({uid: "mock"});
        const result = findUserByUid.data;
        console.log(result)
}
```

When I call **findUser()**,  the follwing exception gets thrown:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: internal]
- node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\prebuilt.rn-31a90691.js:17759:5 in La#convertReference
* http://packager.8e-sbz.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:244218:29 in _errorForResponse
- node_modules\@firebase\functions\dist\index.esm.js:95:12 in codeForHTTPStatus
- node_modules\@firebase\functions\dist\index.esm.js:461:8 in Service.prototype.useFunctionsEmulator
```

What am i doing wrong? Also there's nothing logged in the firebase emulator suite.

**Update:** Firebase function

```
export const findUserByUid = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const foundUser = await admin.auth().getUser(data.uid);
        if (foundUser) {
            return {user: foundUser.email};
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return new https.HttpsError("not-found", error);
    }
    return {user: null};
});
```

Comment: Did you set up your credentials for the emulator so that it can interact with the admin sdk? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional

Comment: and what happens if you call the function directly in the emulator? You can run ```firebase functions:shell``` and then execute the function directly https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann If i call the function directly in the shell i got a response but also following error:
 (node:6820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)

Comment: what happens when you use try/catch in the cloud function and log the error properly? You can later use httpsErrors to return a response that makes more sense https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann Yes then i get no errors from the shell, but still no success by calling the function over firebaseFunction.httpsCallable